# C# graphics.drawImage() crops my Image

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, drawimage

I am trying to put an image on a bigger image. But the inner image was cropped after drawImage(). Here is my code:

```
Bitmap im = new Bitmap("D:\\Steffen\\New folder\\I1\\I1\\" + filename + ".png");
int sizeX = im.Width;
int sizeY = im.Height;
int size = 0;
bool isWidth = false;
if (sizeX > sizeY) 
{ 
    size = sizeX; isWidth = true; 
}
else if(sizeY > sizeX)
{ 
    size = sizeY; isWidth = false; 
}

filename = filename + "New";
Bitmap bg = new Bitmap(size,size);
SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Aqua);

using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bg))
{
    g.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, size, size);
    if (isWidth==true)
    {
        g.DrawImage(im, 0, (size - sizeY) / 2);
    }
    else if(isWidth==false)
    {
        g.DrawImage(im, (size-sizeX)/2, 0);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: No repro.  BTW, you don't have a value for `size` if `sizeX == sizeY`.

Comment: Thanks about that, but still it doesn't not affect to the problem because I'm testing unquadratic images

Comment: the first bitmap'im' has 365x500 pixel with 24 bit depth

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be the resolution of the image is the issue:

Try it like this:

```
Bitmap im = new Bitmap("D:\\Steffen\\New folder\\I1\\I1\\" + filename + ".png");
im.SetResolution(96F, 96F);
```

Comment: yeah! your right. Thanks for the idea. I solved it already by converting the first bitmap's 'bit depth' same as the second `public static Bitmap ConvertTo16bpp(Image img) {
  var bmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555);
  using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    gr.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height));
  return bmp;
}`

Comment: Do note the 96 dpi is not guaranteed to be correct.  It will be less and less correct :)  Graphics.DpiX/Y matters.  It is just easier to use the DrawImage(Image, Rectangle) overload so this just won't matter.